# WebSocket connection to '<firebaseURL>' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, firebase, websocket, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am just trying to get information off my firebase database. I am new to this and I am using Angular 2. I get this error when I look in the console:

WebSocket connection to '(firebaseURL)' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is what I am using to get my data as found on the firebase website:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
```

The strange thing is that it works completely fine - I get the info I want every time I reload, but I still receive this error. It also seems to take a while to get the info from the database -  about 2 or 3 seconds.

edit: solved the problem. Was something to do with the wifi proxy settings